# I want to use the content of a cell in a google sheet to control whether to send an e-mail out or not

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, criteria

I have a spreadsheet for recording customer samples. A column [I] is used to calculate when the original entry date is over a certain period which then displays an overdue message using an if statement. I want to trigger a script to check this column daily and if 'overdue' is found to send an email to an address contained in another column [C]. I am also using another column [J] to return a message when an email has been sent. I am using the script below but am returning errors

1. The script marks all rows in column J with the sent email message
2. I appear to be collecting a bigger array of data have needed [adding two rows the the bottom]

Anyone any ideas?

```
//Setup the function
function autoMail () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    //Get the active spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName( 'TS_Requests' );    //Get the active spread
  var startRow = 3;    // Start of row that going to be process considering row 2 is header
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();    // Get the last row of data to be process
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();    // Get the last column of data to be process
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,lastRow,lastColumn);    //Getting the specific cell to be process
  var data = range.getValues();    // Get the values inside the cell
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;++i){
    var row = data[i];
    var email = row[2];    // Grab the email column. C in this case
    var customer = row[3];    // Grab data for Email body
    var item = row[5];    // Grab data for Email body
    var description = row[6];    // Grab data for Email body
    var status = row[8];    // Grab the column containing the value needed to be checked.
    var EmailSent = row[9]
    if (EmailSent != 'Email_Sent') {    //Prevents e-mail being sent in duplicate
      if(valstatus ='Overdue'){    // Check the values, if it's what's needed, do something
MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Your sample request is overdue', customer + ' - ' + item + ' - ' + description);    // if condition is met, send email
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue('Email_Sent');
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You never initialize or fill `valstatus` before using it in your `if` statement.  Did you mean `status`?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that. Code still completes column J with Email_Sent message for ALL rows not just for ones where column 9 is 'Overdue'

Comment: I'm also building an array which is two rows longer than it should be. For instance i have 3 actual rows of data but the code is building an array that 5 rows long. Consequently the last two rows have no data and so no e-mail addresses, so I get an error when using   MailApp.sendEmail.

Comment: Try changing the single quotes to double for both of your if statements.  Sometimes that makes a difference.  Also, instead of `++i`, try `i++`.

Comment: Working now - Thanks Ron ;-)